# Email without authentication in android

Tags: java, android, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

Can I send e-mail without any authentication?

Like in php:

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: You mean without password ? In java (for android) ?

Comment: @smilyface Yes i mean that

Comment: You need a mail server that's going to let you send mail without authenticating first.  Most are not going to let you do that, or they would soon become a source of spam.

Comment: @BillShannon then how can i develope a custom email client for that mail server please help ..

Comment: Which mail server?  If you already have a mail server that allows you to send mail without authenticating, just connect to it, don't pass a username or password, and send a message.

Comment: @BillShannon please explain how can i connect it to the mail server?

Comment: Uh, using the "connect" method on Store or Transport.  Duh!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaMail, but this is only 50% related since you have to set up at least 1 Email account at a hoster which you will parse the sender's id and the target adress.

At the start of this class, there's this:

```
 // Hier bitte die ensprechenden Attribute jeweils anpassen
GMX("mail.gmx.net", 25, "wildlurk@gmx.de", "yxcvbnm1", "wildlurk@gmx.de"),
GOOGLEMAIL("smtp.googlemail.com", 25, "login", "passwort", "absender"),
ARCOR("mail.arcor.de", 25, "login", "passwort", "absender"),
WEB("smtp.web.de", 25, "login", "passwort", "absender"),
YAHOO("smtp.mail.yahoo.de", 25, "login", "passwort", "absender"),
// Hier können weitere E-Mail Accounts als ENUM angelegt werden
;
```

The first one I created some time ago, you can use it for testing if you want. 
Look out for JavaMail. You will have to use this library unless you want to reinvent everything.

Here's a example program I just took out of their "demo" folder (sorry it's an applet)

HTML : http://pastebin.com/bHkrNNS0
JAVA : http://pastebin.com/88g941SP
DOCS : http://pastebin[dot]com/sgQGRKhJ

One last thing:
If you want the data to be send anonymously (or perhaps hidden=?) i recommend the usage of Java's Serversocket and Socket classes. If you kind of just want to send an id and a quik message I would preferre this as it's faster written and the server itself can handle and save the messages just like an email server would....